# Is it possible to convert an SObject to a Map?

Tags: apex, sobject

Is it possible to convert an SOBject to a Map in a very few short lines of codes?

Comment: Do you mean a list of SObject's? If so, Map<ID, SObject> myMap = new Map<ID, SObject>(mySObjectList); Will give you a map of SOBject's by Id.

Comment: An Sobject has some of the behaviour of a Map<String,Object> - i.e. get/put methods. What are your reasons for wanting to convert an Sobject to a Map<String,Object> (I presume that's what you're after)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but you could do something with the [JSON.deserializeUntyped method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm) as following:

```
testobject__c  tObj =  [SELECT boolfield__c,currencyfield__c,datetimefield__c,formulafield__c,Id,Name,numberfield__c,textfield__c,url_field__c FROM testobject__c limit 1];

Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(tObj));

system.debug(m.values());
system.debug(m.keyset());
```

I however somewhat assume that if you are going to to this in an interative fashion, or for bulky objects, this is not very performant, and you should take this into consideration. Be sure to know why you want to do this in your logic, and consider possible alternatives.

**update:** Salesforce released an apex native method to accomplish this. [See dana's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/164436/119).

Comment: nice use of deserializeUntyped! +1

Comment: Nice smart answer, though agree with "Be sure to know why..."

Comment: This may work but using the native functionality is a better idea.

Answer (score 25):

The `sObject` has a native function [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) that converts from an `sObject` to a `Map<String,Object>`.  This was released in Summer '16 which is probably why the other answers resort to using JSON serialization to accomplish this.

```
Account a = new Account();
a.name = 'TestMapAccount1';
insert a;
a = [select Id,Name from Account where id=:a.Id];
Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = a.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

for (String fieldName : fieldsToValue.keySet()){
    System.debug('field name is ' + fieldName + ', value is ' +
        fieldsToValue.get(fieldName));
}

// Example debug statement output:
// DEBUG|field name is Id, value is 001R0000003EPPkIAO
// DEBUG|field name is Name, value is TestMapAccount1
```

Answer (score 3):

It's doable if you de/serialize to JSON. The below may work but Sdry's untyped approach is superior:

```
Contact contactObject = new Contact(
  FirstName = 'Derp',
  LastName  = 'Herpinson'
);

String data = System.Json.serialize(contactObject);

Map<String,String> contactMap = (Map<String,String>)System.Json.deserialize(
  data.substringBefore('"attributes":{') + data.substringAfter('},'),
  Map<String,String>.class
);

System.debug(contactMap);
//{FirstName=Derp, LastName=Herpinson}
```